# How to implement reactive health indicator having health information from multiple webclients?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to implement reactive health indicator to check health of multiple target services.

However , respective services are json is not getting parsed. I understood that's Mono of Health is having Mono of Map. To remove Mono of Map , if I use block() then also it fails with error as block() is not allowed in reactive call. I tried to use map() function and populate value in another map but no value is being passed to that map and it's not subscribed by caller. Since I am using spring boot actuator I cannot force caller to subscribe so how can I achieve below response in health check

**Desired Response**

```
> "reactiveTarget": {
>             "status": "UP"            {
>               "target1": {
>                   "status": "UP"
>               },
>               "target2": {
>                   "status": "UP"
>               }           }
>         },
```

**Achieved Response**

```
"reactiveTarget": {
            "status": "UP",
            "details": {
                "target1": {
                    "scanAvailable": true
                },
                "holdingsWebClient": {
                    "target2": true
                }
            }
        },
```

**Code used**

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ReactiveTargetHealthIndicator implements ReactiveHealthIndicator {

    private final ApplicationContext context;

    private String overallStatus="UP";

    public ReactiveTargetHealthIndicator(@NonNull ApplicationContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Health> health() {
        return checkTargetServiceHealth().onErrorResume(
                ex -> Mono.just(new Health.Builder().down(ex).build())
        );
    }

    private Mono<Health> checkTargetServiceHealth() {
        var target = this.context;
        Map<String, Mono<Map<String, String>>> targetServiceBeans= new LinkedHashMap<>();
        while (target != null) {
            target.getBeansOfType(WebClient.class)
                    .forEach((name, webclient) -> targetServiceBeans.put(name, createReport(name,webclient)));
            target = target.getParent();
        }
        log.info("Reactive Webclient Beans [{}]", targetServiceBeans); // Bean is empty
        var heathBuilder = new Health.Builder().withDetails(targetServiceBeans);
        return (overallStatus.equals("DOWN") )? Mono.just(heathBuilder.down().build())
                : Mono.just(heathBuilder.up().build());
    }

    private Mono<Map<String, String>> createReport(String name, WebClient webclient) {
        log.info("Reactive Webclient [{}] is triggered", name); // Here name of bean is coming
        return webclient.get()
                .uri("/actuator/health/liveness")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
                })
                .onErrorResume(e -> {
                    log.error("Could not retrieve reactive health status of : {}", name, e);
                    overallStatus="DOWN";
                    return Mono.just(Map.of("status", "DOWN"));
                });
    }
}
```